# Twitch recorder

Tags: python, pycharm, twitch

I'm trying to write code in PyCharm to record stream when my favorite twitch streamer is broadcasting, using this code:

```
import subprocess
import time
import os
import json

streamer_name = "pobr4tski"
quality = "best"
save_folder = "C:/Users/letha/twitch"

if not os.path.exists(save_folder):
    os.mkdir(save_folder)

while True:
    try:
        channels = subprocess.check_output(["streamlink", "--json", f"https://www.twitch.tv/{streamer_name}", quality])
        stream_data = json.loads(channels.decode("utf-8"))
        stream_url = stream_data["streams"][quality]["url"]
        file_name = f"{streamer_name} - {time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')}.mp4" # Create a file name with the current date and time
        file_path = os.path.join(save_folder, file_name)
        print("Stream is live, starting recording...")
        subprocess.call(["streamlink", stream_url, quality, "-o", file_path])
    except:
        print("Stream is offline, checking again in 60 seconds...")
        time.sleep(60)
```

but I have only output `Stream is offline, checking again in 60 seconds...`, even if he is online and broadcasting a broadcast, thank you in advance

I have uninstall python and download it again with all needed pip's, but it's didn't change my situation

Comment: Try to print your exception: `except Exception as e: print(e)`. It might help to know whats actually going wrong

Comment: did it, all time replying :
KeyError: 'streams'

Comment: Did you write the code or did you use ChatGPT, Bing or another AI?

Comment: This means the line `stream_url = stream_data["streams"][quality]["url"]` fails, because stream_data does not contain the key "streams". Check what the dictionary looks like and adjust your keys.

Comment: 70/30
30(is me :з)

Comment: you think I need use my twitch API? such a client_ID, sorry for asking a lot, I trying complete it last 3 days

Answer (score 2):

I think you can omit some of the code, since streamlink automatically pulls the correct stream url.  https://streamlink.github.io/cli.html

```py
while True:
    file_name = f"{streamer_name} - {time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')}.mp4" # Create a file name with the current date and time
    file_path = os.path.join(save_folder, file_name)
    subprocess.call(["streamlink", f"https://www.twitch.tv/{streamer_name}", quality, "-o", file_path])
    print("Stream is live, starting recording...")
except Exception as e:
    print("Stream is offline, checking again in 60 seconds...")
    time.sleep(60)
```

I tested this on my machine and it seems to work if the streamer is online. Didn't test it if they are offline.

Comment: it's work, thank you <3

Comment: I will do my best to make the code work even if my computer is not turned on, thank you for so much help